# Why does the Goroutines take almost identical time as sequential execution?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm calling two functions with Go routine per each and I'm expecting the time it takes to execute them at the same time should be significantly less than if I'm to run them a one at a time. But I'm seeing exactly opposite, it takes the same or sometimes **less** time to run them in parallel.

### Goroutines

```golang
    start := time.Now()
    incomeChan := make(chan func() ([]models.Cashflow, *models.ErrorResponse))
    expenseChan := make(chan func() ([]models.Cashflow, *models.ErrorResponse))

    go func(from, to string, cr *fa.Client, c chan<-func() ([]models.Cashflow, *models.ErrorResponse)) {
        log.Println("fetching income")
        c <- func() ([]models.Cashflow, *models.ErrorResponse) { return incomes(from, to, cr)}
        close(c)
    }(from, to, cr, incomeChan)

    go func(from, to string, cr *fa.Client, c chan<-func() ([]models.Cashflow, *models.ErrorResponse)){
        log.Println("fetching expenses")
        c <- func() ([]models.Cashflow, *models.ErrorResponse) {return expenses(from, to, cr)}
        close(c)
    } (from, to, cr, expenseChan)

    income, inErr := (<- incomeChan)()
    if inErr != nil {
        log.Printf("%#v", inErr)
        w.WriteHeader(inErr.Code)
        fmt.Fprint(w, helper.JsonStringify(inErr))
        return
    }
    log.Println("income fetch completed")

    expense, exErr := (<- expenseChan)()
    if exErr != nil {
        log.Printf("%#v", exErr)
        w.WriteHeader(exErr.Code)
        fmt.Fprint(w, helper.JsonStringify(exErr))
        return
    }
    log.Println("expense fetch completed")
    fmt.Printf("%.2fs elapsed\n", time.Since(start).Seconds())
```

#### Output

```
3.33s elapsed
2.79s elapsed
3.37s elapsed
```

### Sequential

```golang
    income, inErr := incomes(from, to, cr)
    if inErr != nil {
        log.Printf("%#v", inErr)
        w.WriteHeader(inErr.Code)
        fmt.Fprint(w, helper.JsonStringify(inErr))
        return
    }
    
    expense, exErr := expenses(from, to, cr)
    if exErr != nil {
        log.Printf("%#v", exErr)
        w.WriteHeader(exErr.Code)
        fmt.Fprint(w, helper.JsonStringify(exErr))
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("%.2fs elapsed\n", time.Since(start).Seconds())
```

#### Output

```
2.98s elapsed
3.03s elapsed
2.70s elapsed
```

Is it me that doing something wrong here? I was expecting it to spend less time with the Goroutine.

If anyone has any clue as to what I might be doing wrong here or has any suggestions, much appreciated.

Comment: Oddly, I made a simpler one with sleep on the playground and that works as expected, just not mine. https://play.golang.org/p/kwY2mOeSuwO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To preface this, you're confusing parallelism with concurrency. Goroutines deal with concurrency, not parallelism. For more background info on the difference, one of the creator's of Go has a talk called [Concurrency is not Parallelism](https://blog.golang.org/waza-talk).

Now onto an actual answer.

Your goroutines don't actually handle any of the processing of either function, and instead send a function that calls `expenses` and `incomes`, of which you then call sequentially. This means that the actual result of `incomes()` isn't calculated until you call `income, inErr := (<- incomeChan)()`.

Essentially, your "Goroutines" example is functionally identical to your "Sequential" example, but with the additional overhead that comes with goroutines, as they are not guaranteed to be scheduled immediately.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now you explain that, thanks. Is there any way I can make it concurrent without changing the underlying code?

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne you could have your goroutines calculate the value, and then change the type of your channels from a function to a new struct that contains  `[]models.Cashflow, *models.ErrorResponse` as members and handle them accordingly.

Comment: hmm, I was trying to avoid having to do that. But that might be the best solution for it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: FYI, after that change, it only takes half of the time now `1.52s elapsed`.